# Regular expression OR in python findall

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am trying to use the regualr expression

```
re.findall("void (D|S)TC_.+\(\)", testCaseFile)
```

My expectation is the above expression returns list

```
void DTC_Sample_01()
void STC_Sample_02()
```

But it should ignore

`void ZTC_Sample_03()` or any other.

But it is not working as expected

Comment: Try: `re.findall(r"void [DS]TC_.+?\(\)", testCaseFile)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parenthesis you are using tells `findall()` to match the pattern and give you back **only** the contents of the parenthesis. Using `?:` you are matching the pattern as previously, but instead you get the whole match.

```
re.findall("void (?:D|S)TC_.+\(\)", testCaseFile)
```